# How do i update a field in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My goal is to update `timeleft` field on every object in the itemSchema.

```
const ItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    time: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    timeleft: { type: Number, default: 24 }
});
```

For example in order for me to update every object in the `ItemSchema`

```
ItemSchema.methods.calculateTime = function() { // Done check it one hour

  var currentTime = moment() // Get current Time
  var timeStored = moment.utc(this.time).local().format(); // Convert this.time UTC to local time
  var timeDiff = currentTime.diff(timeStored, 'h'); // See the difference in time example - 7
  this.timeleft -= timeDiff; // Deduct timeleft witht he timeDiff , result would be 17
  this.save(); // Simple save it to the database
}
```

API example

```
app.get('/allItems', function(req, res) {
    Item.find({}, function(err, items) {
      // I want to run items.calculateTime(); but it is not possible.
      // How would I run calculateTime function on the array of objects?
    });
});
```

My goal is to keep checking the time difference and save it to the time left

Data example

```
timeleft: 24

// after calculateTime
time: 17 

Because I want to show this to the User

// 17 hours left
```

How would I do this to array of objects, instead of single object?

Comment: Looking at your use case I would not save this value to the DB, but calculate it dynamically upon querying. Have a look at Mongoose's virtual getters.

Comment: So data won't be saved to the `timeleft` field?

Comment: Yes. As far as I understood, it can be calculated from the `time` property, right?

Comment: time is a date type, the reason why i added `timeleft`, so that in the future I could query based on the `timeleft` field

Comment: For example if `timeleft` is `0` then, don't show this content to user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your use case I would suggest to modify your approach to the problem. Obviously you're creating items with an "expiry date" (or something similar, I'll be using the term "expired" in the following). The expiry is 24 hours from the time where the item was created.

I would not **save** the value for `timeLeft` to the DB, but rather **recalculate** it dynamically upon querying. (1) It's redundant, as it can be calculated from the current time and the `time` value, as far as I understood your question, (2) you would have to update the `timeleft` property continuously which seems awkward.

You can make use of Mongoose's [virtuals](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#virtuals).

Changes to the Schema to make sure, that the virtuals are returned when creating objects:

```
const ItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  time: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
}, {
  // enable, to have the property available, 
  // when invoking toObject or toJSON
  toJSON: {
    virtuals: true
  },
  toObject: {
    virtuals: true
  }
});
```

Define the virtual property `timeLeft` (I changed the code to work without `moment`):

```
// the virtual property, which is not stored in the DB,
// but calculated after querying the database
ItemSchema.virtual('timeLeft').get(function() {
  var millisecondsDifference = Date.now() - this.time.getTime();
  var hoursDifference = millisecondsDifference / (1000 * 60 * 60);
  return Math.max(0, 24 - hoursDifference); // cap to 24 hours
});
```

You cannot query on virtual properties, because they obviously do not exist in the database. Instead, when you want to query for items which have reached their expiry date, you can search for items which have been created within the last 24 hours. In order to do that conveniently and have that code at a central place, you can attach a static method to your schema, which you can call using `ItemModel.findNonExpired`:

```
// put the logic for querying non-expired items into
// its own static function, which makes it easier to
// reuse this functionality and understand what's going on
ItemSchema.statics.findNonExpired = function(callback) {
  return this.find({
    time: {
      // find items which have a time within 
      // the last 24 hours
      $gt: new Date(Date.now() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
    }
  }, callback);
};
const ItemModel = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);
```

Demo:

```
// create and save some some test items
const items = [
  { name: 'created now' },
  { name: 'created an hour ago', time: new Date(Date.now() - 1000 * 60 * 60) },
  { name: 'created yesterday', time: new Date(Date.now() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) },
  { name: 'created two days ago', time: new Date(Date.now() - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 2) },
];
ItemModel.create(items, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  ItemModel.findNonExpired(function(err, items) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(items);
  });
});
```

[edit] This is now a full walkthrough, which you should be able to copy and paste without requiring any big changes.

Comment: I edited the question to include, the api that will find all the items. The question is where should I put `$gt: new Date()`?

Comment: and in the virtual, how would I set `timeleft` as 24?, is it simply `this.timeleft = 24`?

Comment: And I tried to query, but seems like it doesn't return `timeleft` property.

Comment: @sinusGob Edited answer.

Comment: So technically, I don't even need to use virtual? Since `const query` has no relation with virtual at all, but what if I want to use virtual instead?

Comment: And `timeleft` property is not part of the JSON response

Comment: This is not "either or". The virtual is necessary. Without it, you'll have no property `timeleft` (sorry, there was still an error in the code, check the edited answer again, please). And: You **cannot** query on a virtual, that was the reason I suggested to change the query.

Comment: Do i need to include `toObject` or `toJSON` ?

Comment: Im really at lost right, been tearing my hair since yesterday. If you could help me. I looked at the docs but seems it doesn't show full example

Comment: @sinusGob I've created a full walkthrough. Have a look.

Comment: This is truly amazing! Now i get it.

Comment: I want to ask you regarding this formula `new Date(Date.now() - 1000 * 60 * 60)` I console.log the data and the difference is only 1 hour.

Comment: if the current time is `14:43:04` , after the formula `13:43:04` and both have the same date.

Comment: Yes, this was an error and should of course be fixed in the query.