# How do I include a virtual field in API response using Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

How do I include a virtual field in a JSON response

```
const ItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  time: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

ItemSchema.virtual('timeleft').get(function() {
  this.timeleft = 24
 
  var currentTime = moment(); 
  var timeStored = moment.utc(this.time).local().format(); 
  this.timeleft -= currentTime.diff(timeStored, 'h');

  
});
```

API call

```
app.get('/getAllItems', function(req, res, next) {
   Item.find({}, function(err, items) {
     res.json(items);
   });
});
```

So technically the response won't include virtual timeleft field. Am I missing something?

```
[
 {
   name: "nike",
   time: "21/2/22"

  },

  {
   name: "adidas",
   time: "21/2/22"

  },
]
```

Comment: If you use `toJSON()` or `toObject()` (or use `JSON.stringify()` on a mongoose document) mongoose will not include virtuals by default. Pass `{ virtuals: true }` to either `toObject()` or `toJSON()`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i update a field in mongodb?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41636515/how-do-i-update-a-field-in-mongodb)

Comment: Is this question about querying or just about getting? To clarify, I would like to how to do  ```Item.find({ timeleft: 5000 })```

Answer (score 20):

```
// use Schema like this        
const ItemSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    time: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
}, {
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
});

ItemSchema.virtual('timeleft').get(function() {
    // this.timeleft = 24
    var currentTime = moment();
    var timeStored = moment.utc(this.time).local().format();
    console.log(" ====== 000 ======== ", currentTime.diff(timeStored, 'h'))
    return this.timeleft = currentTime.diff(timeStored, 'h');
});

const Item = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);

new Item({
    name: 'Axl'
}).save((err, result) => { 
    console.log("=== err ", err, "=== result ", result)
});

Item.find({}, function(err, items) {
    console.log("=========", items)
});
```

Comment: I guess this answers his particular problem, but not the greater question: how to query virtual fields, which doesn't seem possible...

Answer (score 6):

According to Mongoose docs Mongoose virtuals are not stored in MongoDB, which means you can't query based on Mongoose virtuals.

```
// Will **not** find any results, because `domain` is not stored in
// MongoDB.
const doc = await User.findOne({ domain: 'gmail.com' });
doc; // undefined
```

If you want to query by a computed property, you should set the property using a custom setter or pre save middleware.

Answer (score -3):

Modify your schema as shown below:

```
const ItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    time: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },  // <-- These properties will configure
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }     //     model to include virtuals
});
```

Modify your API call as follows:

```
app.get('/getAllItems', function(req, res, next) {
    Item.find({}, function(err, items) {
        res.json(items.toObject());  // <-- use .toObject() or .toJSON()
    });
});
```

Comment: I got error, when I include `toObject: { virtuals: true }` and `toJSON: {virtuals: true}` it says undefined type `undefined at toObject.virtuals`

Comment: `    throw new TypeError('Undefined type `' + name + '` at `' + path +
    ^

TypeError: Undefined type `undefined` at `toObject.virtuals`
  Did you try nesting Schemas? You can only nest using refs or arrays.`

Comment: Any idea which line of your code is actually throwing this error? Does the query get completed (callback is called)?

Comment: Also try changing the `ItemSchema` to move `toObject` and `toJSON` to schema options like this -->. 

    `const ItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        name: String,
        time: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
    }, { toObject: { virtuals: true }, toJSON: { virtuals: true });`

Comment: toObject and toJSON code are the second parameter of Schema. So it should have been Schema({},{toObject:.., toJSON:...})